# Why does my compiled code not run in C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I made a simple ***c++*** program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  for (int i = 0; i >=; i++){
     std::cout << i << "\n";
  }
return 0;
}
```

It compiles but the output `.exe` doesn't run.

Edit: I used GNAT Studio 2021 compiler.

Comment: Pretty sure it does not compile. `i >=; ` Run as long as `i` is larger than or equal to ... ?

Comment: Note that your code also has a logical flaw. `i` start's at `0`, the loop will run as long as `i` is larger than or equal to some missing value and `i` will only grow. So your loop will either run never or forever, depending on the missing value.

Answer (score 1):

The termination condition is incorrect : `i >=`.

You can choose a number of turn of the loop, for exemple 10 with : `i<=10`.

Comment: I did that! But it still didn't work! Why did you close it?!

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. At all. I'm angry at you for closing the question >:(

Comment: Oh wait, sorry I said that.... I edited it so you would understand the problem more and... maybe... would you pls reopen it? Please?

Comment: @sharkdude The code you've shown can't possibly compile on any non-broken compiler, so the question was closed as "not-reproducible". I also pointed out in the comments above why your code is flawed, if it would compile. Was anything unclear about this? This answer gives you good alternative that will work.